# Is "depending" an adverb in this context?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, british-english, learning

is this text:

"does the meaning of a song change depending on who wrote it?"

is "depending" an adverb modifying "change" in this case?

Answer (score 0):

It is the -ing form of a verb.  This is often called a "participle", and this participle heads the phrase "depending on who wrote it".

Participle phrases can act as modifiers in sentences, in a similar way to adverbs.  But it is not correct to say that it *is* an adverb.